# Maven does not get jar's

Tags: maven, jstl

I have my project and when I try to execute, I get the following error:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pweb/select.jsp(1,1) /pweb/pages/header.jsp(2,0) The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:300)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:333)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:442)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1400)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1778)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pweb/select.jsp(1,1) /V3/pages/header.jsp(2,0) The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:300)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:333)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:442)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1400)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1778)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, as you can see below my `pom.xml` is like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>pweb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>





    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So I exported my project to a .war to see if my jar's are in there, but they aren't, causing that JasperException, but why is Maven not getting the jar's when building it? thanks.

**[UPDATE]** In case you want to see my jsp page using JSTL Tag:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: Why have you changed the default location of `src` instead of using the defaults of Maven `src/main/java`, `src/main/webapp`?

Comment: it created automatically, but the project was already in this format

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat you need JSTL implementation, not only API. So you need another dependency (for Tomcat 6 use JSTL 1.2):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This jar contains both API and implementation. See more details in wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info.

Also notice that your servlet-api and jsp-api dependencies should have `<scope>provided<scope>`.